# Dataframe does not have separated columns for every data after reading CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am loading a csv file in order to read it in a dataframe. But, when I load it, I got the dataframe which was not separated.

The data in a CSV file is as below,

```
Name;OffsetBarrierX;MeanF;MaxF;Thickness
sim1;88.416;-120140.0402;453487.6875;2.4
sim2;-108.321;-119949.118;447437.9688;2.4
sim3;-89.221;-119324.1906;576758.625;2.4
sim4;-89.221;-119324.1906;576758.625;2.4
sim5;-87.488;-117527.1688;574904.5625;2.4
sim6;-11.1424;-183188.6846;763354;2.4
```

I wrote followig line of code,

```
path = '../00_Data/Res_Overl_A.csv'
pd.read_csv(path, sep = ';')
```

I got the following output,

```
Name;OffsetBarrierX;MeanF;MaxF;Thickness
0   sim1;88.416;-120140.0402;453487.6875;2.4
1   sim2;-108.321;-119949.118;447437.9688;2.4
2   sim3;-89.221;-119324.1906;576758.625;2.4
3   sim4;-87.488;-117527.1688;574904.5625;2.4
4   sim5;-11.1424;-183188.6846;763354;2.4
5   sim6;-82.713;-121320.2933;608878.1875;2.4
6   sim7;-27.194;-172708.102;747944.625;2.4
```

So as you can see, there is no change. I need an output which has different data in different column of dataframe. How can I make different columns for every data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't reproduce OP's problem as when I create a csv with the data indicated above, [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) reads without any issue

```
path = r'C:\Users\johndoe\Documents\Python\Challenges\StackOverflow\0108.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';')

[Out]:

   Name  OffsetBarrierX        MeanF         MaxF  Thickness
0  sim1         88.4160 -120140.0402  453487.6875        2.4
1  sim2       -108.3210 -119949.1180  447437.9688        2.4
2  sim3        -89.2210 -119324.1906  576758.6250        2.4
3  sim4        -89.2210 -119324.1906  576758.6250        2.4
4  sim5        -87.4880 -117527.1688  574904.5625        2.4
5  sim6        -11.1424 -183188.6846  763354.0000        2.4
```

---

However, given OP's problem, one approach would be to store the content of the CSV in a variable. Let's call the variable `csv`

```
csv = """Name;OffsetBarrierX;MeanF;MaxF;Thickness
sim1;88.416;-120140.0402;453487.6875;2.4
sim2;-108.321;-119949.118;447437.9688;2.4
sim3;-89.221;-119324.1906;576758.625;2.4
sim4;-89.221;-119324.1906;576758.625;2.4
sim5;-87.488;-117527.1688;574904.5625;2.4
sim6;-11.1424;-183188.6846;763354;2.4"""
```

Now, [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) should solve the problem

```
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep=';')

[Out]:

   Name  OffsetBarrierX        MeanF         MaxF  Thickness
0  sim1         88.4160 -120140.0402  453487.6875        2.4
1  sim2       -108.3210 -119949.1180  447437.9688        2.4
2  sim3        -89.2210 -119324.1906  576758.6250        2.4
3  sim4        -89.2210 -119324.1906  576758.6250        2.4
4  sim5        -87.4880 -117527.1688  574904.5625        2.4
5  sim6        -11.1424 -183188.6846  763354.0000        2.4
```